# Clicking link within accordian opens next section

Tags: jquery, html, css

my accordion is a simple jquery accordion, when you click on the button(row) it expands content as usual. My question is, how can i get the next slide to open after also clicking a link within the open content pane?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfksm/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a link within a tab, you can create an event handler to open the next tab like this:

```
<a href="#" class="openTabLink">Next</a>
```

JQuery:

```
    $('.openTabLink').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.accordionContent').next('.accordionButton').click();
        return false;           
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfksm/5/

Comment: genius sir. not sure why i didnt put 2 and 2 together. thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks, hit accept if that answers your question and welcome to SO.

Comment: what about opening the first accordion panel by default with the animation on load?

Comment: Change `$('.accordionContent').hide();` to `$('.accordionContent:not(:first)').hide();`

Comment: This is an old answer, but any idea how to implement this with Bootstrap collapse accordion?

Comment: @Jennifer all the code you need is in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Answer (score 0):

For opening the first accordion panel by default on load, add `$('.accordionContent:first').show();` after `$('.accordionContent').hide();`.

See @js1568's [**Revised jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/sY5nZ/1/).